# event that occurs when interacting with a GroupBox control?

Tags: c#, .net, events

As stated in the title of this post, is it possible to trigger an event when a user will interact on one of the controls present in the GroupBox.
Let me explain, in fact I have a groupBox composed of textbox, combobox,...
So I would just like to be able to activate an event when the user is going to interact with one of these controls.
Is that possible ? (I don't find on the Internet)
Thank in advance ;)

Comment: Can you explain bit more with example? What should happen to textbox and combobox when user click on GroupBox?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First of all, please use tags. There are dozens of UI frameworks with group boxes. Secondly, please provide some code with a specific issue you faced. Otherwise your question will be likely closed as too broad or unclear what you are asking. Thirdly, what do you mean interact? Hovering by the mouse? Focusing? Changing their text/other properties?

Answer (score 0):

The `GroupBox` has an `Enter` event that is fired before when a control inside GroupBox is entered.

Example:

```
groupBox1.Enter += groupBox1_Enter;
textBox1.Enter += textBox1_Enter;
```

and the handlers:

```
private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("groupBox1_Enter");
}

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("textBox1_Enter");
}
```

gives the output:

```
groupBox1_Enter
textBox1_Enter
```